# A radio button within the result of another

Tags: javascript, radio-button

I can't seem to find any information on whether what I would like to do is possible or not.

Here is my current code: http://jsfiddle.net/richerdk/zudCf/

Is it possible to have a radio button within the result of another radio button ex:

User selects yes radio button this is the result:

```
 <div id="div1" class="tab">
    <p>Why do you think the sky is blue, is blue your favorite colour? </p>
</div>
```

Could I add another yes/no radio button inside of this?

If not how would I go about writing if else statements so I could have different results based on the yes/no selections.

Thanks,

Richerd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With you current code you need to update the nav var

```
var nav = document.getElementById('nav').getElementsByTagName('input');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pjdicke/zudCf/2/

Comment: This is awesome thanks, however one last piece. How would I add more text based on the yes/no you added? I'm unable to reference it.

Answer (score 0):

It's valid but you will need to set different **name** attributes to them and set as **disable** the radio buttons when not active or the will be serialized on submit. A server side validation will do too.